# Find users who have made two or more orders with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

With the following Rails models:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :orders
    end

    class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

I want a query that finds users who:

- placed 2 or more orders in the past, and in the same query
- filter by users who placed orders over the month

I tried something like this:

```
    start_date = 1.month.ago

    users = User.joins(:orders)
      .where('orders.created_at >= ?', start_date)
      .having('COUNT(orders.user_id) > 1')
      .group('orders.user_id')
```

But it didn't work. Please help. I can't work out from the docs how to use the `having` clause, or if it's the right approach.
Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Update: Here's the sql query generated by Rails:

```
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM "users" 
    INNER JOIN "orders" 
    ON "orders"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
    WHERE (orders.created_at >= '2017-05-02') 
    GROUP BY orders.user_id 
    HAVING COUNT(orders.user_id) > 1
```

Comment: Explain *didn't work*.

Comment: I got an array of `#<User id: nil>` I was hoping for a collection of users.

Comment: Can you post the *SQL query* that had run in the background?

Comment: @Pavan I've updated with the sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query to find all the users with more than 2 orders in the past along with their latest order's created_at. And then select users with their  latest order's created_at less than a month. Like this:

```
repeat_users = User.joins(:orders).group("(users.id) having count(users.id) > 2").select("users.*", "max(orders.created_at) as last_order_time")

past_month_users = repeat_users.select{|user| user.last_order_time > Time.now - 1.month}
```

Comment: very inefficient..also, `select` and `pluck` together?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @MohitSrivastava I have a question about your queries. Where you have `.having('COUNT(orders.user_id) > 1')` would that only include orders after the start date? I need the count to include all orders the user has made in the past. Thanks!
With your third code block you can do without `pluck` and it will still work and be fore efficient. That way the query only hits the database once.

Comment: Edited my answer to include one query only. I clearly misunderstood the question, however in my defence, the initial question earlier wasn't exactly this. Apologies though. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks @MohitSrivastava. Yep my bad, I updated the question because the original was obviously not clear. There's an art to asking questions ;)